# How to support TLS 1 and TLS 1.1 with haproxy 2.4 and OpenSSL 3?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, haproxy, openssl

I am trying to support TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 with haproxy 2.4.18 (and OpenSSL 3.0.2) on Ubuntu 22.04.

I have followed [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/), "Old" configuration, slightly modified, adding `:@SECLEVEL=1` and `ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0`

```
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305\
:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECD\
HE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC\
3-SHA:@SECLEVEL=1
    ssl-default-bind-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0 no-tls-tickets

    ssl-default-server-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY13\
05:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:E\
CDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-C\
BC3-SHA:@SECLEVEL=1
    ssl-default-server-ciphersuites TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    ssl-default-server-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.0 no-tls-tickets
```

This is the error that I get:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect myserver.com:443 -tls1_1
CONNECTED(00000003)
40770031637F0000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 80
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 127 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1676996842
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

On the server, haproxy log reports a "SSL handshake failure".

And this is `haproxy -vv` output, apparently with support for TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1:

```
# haproxy -vv
HAProxy version 2.4.18-0ubuntu1.2 2023/02/13 - https://haproxy.org/
Status: long-term supported branch - will stop receiving fixes around Q2 2026.
Known bugs: http://www.haproxy.org/bugs/bugs-2.4.18.html
Running on: Linux 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64
Build options :
  TARGET  = linux-glibc
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = cc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fwrapv -Wno-address-of-packed-member -Wno-unused-label -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-clobbered -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-cast-function-type -Wtype-limits -Wshift-negative-value -Wshift-overflow=2 -Wduplicated-cond -Wnull-dereference
  OPTIONS = USE_PCRE2=1 USE_PCRE2_JIT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_LUA=1 USE_SLZ=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1 USE_PROMEX=1
  DEBUG   = 

Feature list : +EPOLL -KQUEUE +NETFILTER -PCRE -PCRE_JIT +PCRE2 +PCRE2_JIT +POLL -PRIVATE_CACHE +THREAD -PTHREAD_PSHARED +BACKTRACE -STATIC_PCRE -STATIC_PCRE2 +TPROXY +LINUX_TPROXY +LINUX_SPLICE +LIBCRYPT +CRYPT_H +GETADDRINFO +OPENSSL +LUA +FUTEX +ACCEPT4 -CLOSEFROM -ZLIB +SLZ +CPU_AFFINITY +TFO +NS +DL +RT -DEVICEATLAS -51DEGREES -WURFL +SYSTEMD -OBSOLETE_LINKER +PRCTL -PROCCTL +THREAD_DUMP -EVPORTS -OT -QUIC +PROMEX -MEMORY_PROFILING

Default settings :
  bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Built with multi-threading support (MAX_THREADS=64, default=8).
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports : TLSv1.0 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
Built with Lua version : Lua 5.3.6
Built with the Prometheus exporter as a service
Built with network namespace support.
Built with libslz for stateless compression.
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND
Built with PCRE2 version : 10.39 2021-10-29
PCRE2 library supports JIT : yes
Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with gcc compiler version 11.3.0

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.

Available multiplexer protocols :
(protocols marked as <default> cannot be specified using 'proto' keyword)
              h2 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H2       flags=HTX|CLEAN_ABRT|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
            fcgi : mode=HTTP       side=BE        mux=FCGI     flags=HTX|HOL_RISK|NO_UPG
              h1 : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1       flags=HTX|NO_UPG
       <default> : mode=HTTP       side=FE|BE     mux=H1       flags=HTX
            none : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS     flags=NO_UPG
       <default> : mode=TCP        side=FE|BE     mux=PASS     flags=

Available services : prometheus-exporter
Available filters :
    [SPOE] spoe
    [CACHE] cache
    [FCGI] fcgi-app
    [COMP] compression
    [TRACE] trace
```

Why is this not working and how can I fix it? Thanks!

I know these are obsolete protocols but I would like to support users that have old browsers for whatever reason.

Comment: I've found that testssl is useful in diagnosing this specific issue.

`apt install testssl.sh`
`testssl --protocols localhost:443`

Answer (score 4):

With OpenSSL 3.0.1 they (rightfully) [moved TLS 1.0 and 1.1 to security level 0](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-3.0-notes.html), because they're utterly useless and insecure. It's a horrible idea to support these protocols, it's actually worse than plain HTTP, since it gives you a false sense of security. In your cipher suite generator, you're using SECLEVEL 1, which clearly [ain't gonna fly](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/openssl-command-line/understanding-security-levels.html) with these protocols anymore.

[TLS 1.2](https://caniuse.com/tls1-2) support has been added to pretty much all browsers almost 10 years ago. Why on Earth would you want to support clients more than a decade old? Infosec is not a matter of "whatever reason". Especially if it renders your HTTP security completely breakable.

On my sites, even TLS 1.2 usage was so low (3% maybe) a year ago that I just went ahead and bumped the requirement to TLS 1.3. Which has been supported by browsers for a good 5 years already. If a visitor wants to use ancient, insecure stuff, be my guest - just not on my sites.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's only about a 1% of the users but the question is, do I allow them to use the website with a low security protocol, or do I reject them?  What do they prefer?  The users with updated browsers can anyway use TLS 1.2 or 1.3 so, as long as I understand, they will not be affected by the website supporting TLS 1 and 1.1 at the same time.

Comment: You reject them. `ssl-default-bind-options ssl-min-ver TLSv1.2` and anything older will be discarded.